# how to send some data to specific url when an alert triggered in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am familiar with the webhook in pine script. webhook's problem is that does not allowed to send data with post curl.

how can I send some data (multiple float values) to a url when a statement in my indicator is happens ?

thanks in advance

Comment: How are you sending it now? You should be able to do multiple floats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely send data with the webhook.

When you define an Alert, you set the `Alert name` and `Message` fields. The `Alert name` is just a string (for you, to differentiate among alerts), but the `Message` field can contain built-in Pine variables and you can set values to those built-in variables, in your script, runtime. On the Alert creation window there is a text "You can use special placeholders such as {{close}}..." and a question mark, which leads to the documentation.

Ie.: you can set your own variable (say, `al_mes`) to a certain value (which can control your app on the other end of the webhook) and when you call `strategy.entry()` it will accept an alert message field, where you should put in that `al_mes` variable:

```
strategy.entry(id='Above Open', direction=strategy.long, alert_message=al_mes, comment = 'To the Moon')
```

That alert message value will be put into the built-in variable `alert_message` which you can place into the alert creation window's Message field as `{{strategy.order.alert_message}}`.

When the Alert is triggered, the webhook will be queried with a HTTP POST request and the contents of `{{strategy.order.alert_message}}` which is equivalent to `al_mes` will be put into the request as POST DATA.

This is how 3Commas.io bots work with Tradingview Custom Signal.